# Сокращенные команды для создания файла

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Можно ли как-нибудь создавать скрипт сразу с установленным битом на исполнение?

И вроде как-то можно через программу *cat* с помощью перенаправлений создать файл и тут же его редактировать?

Comment: Можно написать скрипт, который будет последовательно создавать файл и давать ему права на запуск, в качестве аргумента принимать имя файла. Просто положите этот скрипт в директорию, которая прописана в PATH и сможете запускать его отовсюду.

Comment: Зачем?! Устанавливайте атрибуты тогда, когда необходимо.

Comment: Приведите «длинную» команду, чтобы было ясно что вы хотите сделать.  Явно упомяните почему вы хотите её сократить для ясности.

Comment: umask - интересная команда